# UML Use case for Online Quiz Application

Tags: android, uml, use-case

I am trying to create a UML Use Case design for the Online Quiz Application for Android that I am working on. I got confused after designing this and I don't know if this is enough. This is the result that I have come up with:

[image]

As you can see above, I am not sure if this make sense. What I'm really doing here is when the user open the application, they will either login, register or login as guest. Thereafter, the web-server will check the details of the user and continue to play the quiz once it's valid. The user can also login as guest to play the quiz. They also have an option there to track their performance on quiz, request a subject or rate and give feedback. When they play quiz, obviously the questions will be generated from the web-server. I am not sure if this fits the process. Please comment if you think this is fine or if you think that I need some improvement here just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been covered over and over and over here on stack overflow.

Comment: Login is no use case at all. Where is the added value?

Answer (score 0):

You should distinct registered users and guests. They are different agents.

On the other hand, your web-server is not an agent. He has no his own acts, no initiative, he only reacts to actions of users. I would remove it. ( you can leave it if you want - I see your reasons - but normally you should escape using parts of your system as agents - it does not belong to the standard use case language)

Rate and both checks do not belong to Play Quiz. At all.

Request subject is not extended by Play Quiz, but included.

Check Login is excessive. Or Login without it is excessive. One use case is enough.

Updating the quiz comes after questions generation? I bet not. Their connection should be turned back.

There is only one login. There will be no separate components for login user and login guest.

Registered user cannot play quiz. Do you really need that?

Play Quiz should be connected to registered user and to guest.

Connection login-play belongs to state or sequence diagram, not to use case. Disconnect them.

And remember, the only if that can work in use case is "if A IS B, then it does this and that"

If an agent can do A and B, or A or B, or A and after that B, is irrelevant for the use case diagram. Agent can do A.  Connect them. Agent can do B. Connect them. That's all.